# Bare bones SVG (vector) drawing library for C#

Tags: c#, drawing, svg

I have searched for a bare bones SVG drawing library for C# with no luck. I just want to be able to place nodes with handles, connected to each other with Bezier curved lines, and move them around to create shapes. Nothing else. Everything I have found so far is many degrees of magnitude overkill. Does such a simple thing exist?  It would obviously save a lot of time if I don't have to write it myself. Thanks.